# Scheme redefine a list

Tags: scheme, blackjack, playing-cards

I have a list called hand and another one called deck, the main goal here is to take the first card (or element ) in the list deck and put it in the list hand when i call the fnction draw...

```
> (draw hand deck)
(2 C)
> (draw hand deck)
(2 C) (3 H) 
> (draw hand deck)
(2 C) (3 H) (K D)
```

but everytime i call it the hand never changes value... 
I'm clueless is there a way like in O-Object to change the content of hand permenantly?

and i initialy define hand empty because the player has no card to start.

```
(define hand '())
```

Answer (score 1):

A functional solution, with `draw` being side-effect free:

```
;; Returns a cons whose car will be the new hand and cdr being the
;; rest of the original deck
(define (draw deck hand)
    (if (not (null? deck))
        (cons (cons (car deck) hand) (cdr deck))
        (cons hand ())))

;; Gets the new hand from the cons returned by draw.
(define (hand cards) (car cards))

;; Gets the new deck from the cons returned by draw.
(define (deck cards) (cdr cards))

;; test
(define cards (draw '(1 2 3 4 5) ()))
cards
=> ((1) 2 3 4 5)
(hand cards)
=> (1)
(deck cards)
=> (2 3 4 5)
;; draw again
(set! cards (draw (deck cards) (hand cards)))
cards
=> ((2 1) 3 4 5)
(hand cards)
=> (2 1)
(deck cards)
=> (3 4 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the contents of a list, but you can change which list a name refers to.  So:

```
(let ((some-list '("post")))
 (display "initially: ")
 (display some-list)
 (newline)
 (set! some-list (cons "first" some-list))
 (display "added first: ")
 (display some-list)
 (newline)
 (set! some-list '(a completely new list))
 (display "finally: ")
 (display some-list)
 (newline)
 some-list)
```

Now each of the lists '("post") '("first" "post") and '(a completely new list) are unchangeable ("immutable") lists, but the name some-list first points to one, then another, then the third.

Caveat: For many problems, you will want to avoid set! and try to think about the problem a different way.  For example, if you work with worlds and universes for your game, 
http://pre.plt-scheme.org/plt/doc/teachpack/2htdpuniverse.html
then you'll want your updaters to return a new state of the world rather than using set! to modify the old one.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, and next you will find that changing what list a name refers to inside a function will not change what the name refers to from the perspective of whoever called the function.  So:

```
(define (foo lst)
  (set! lst '(hi))
  (display "within foo: ")
  (display lst)
  (newline)
  lst)
(define my-list '(hello))
(foo my-list)
(display "after foo: ") 
(display my-list)
(newline)
(set! my-list (foo my-list))
(display "using the result of foo: ")
(display my-list)
(newline)
```

Answer (score 0):

Vijay has the best solution for Scheme. However, if you *really* want to make this work by changing the lists permanently, you'll need to use `set-car!` and `set-cdr!`. This is not natural in Scheme, and requires a couple of hacks to make it work:

First define `hand` and `deck`:

```
(define hand '(dummy))
(define deck '((2 C) (3 H) (K D)))
```

`hand` has to start with an existing element so that it has some existing list structure to modify. You can't use `set-car!` and `set-cdr!` with nil ( `'()` ).

Now write `draw`:

```
(define (draw from to)
  ; push the top element of `from` onto `to`
  (set-cdr! to (copy to))
  (set-car! to (car from))
  ; pop the top element of `from` off
  (set-car! deck (cadr deck))
  (set-cdr! deck (cddr deck)))
; also we need to define copy
(define (copy l)
  (map (lambda (x) x) l))
```

This means the last element of your hand will always be dummy. It would be better to add a check for the initial case and overwrite it instead of pushing:

```
(define (draw from to)
  ; push the top element of `from` onto `to` (just overwrite the first time)
  (when (pair? (cdr to))
    (set-cdr! to (copy to)))
  (set-car! to (car from))
  ; pop the top element of `from` off
  (set-car! deck (cadr deck))
  (set-cdr! deck (cddr deck)))
```

Also you should check that `from` isn't empty before doing anything.